# renderas pdf "PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid", position: fixed;

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf, renderas

I am trying to create a pdf using a Visualforce page with `renderas="pdf"` tag but I get below error message

> PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid.

Here is my code below:

```
<apex:page standardController="WorkOrder" extensions="InstallationCertPageController" 
    renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
    ...myStyle...
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...some code...
        <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 11px; right: 0px;" >
            <img src="***image url***"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get it that the real problem is the inline CSS `position: fixed;`.

It worked until Salesforce update winter 18.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: So, if you remove that style property, does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried

Comment: so, does it work?

Comment: comment few blocks -> run the page; run until you narrow down the exact error.

Comment: Hi @Daniele, did you ever get this resolved? I'm now encountering the same issue with "position: running(header)".

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things that i can say, first check whether all html tags in the VF page are closed properly and secondly, since you using inline CSS style then set the API version later than 28.

Comment: Thanks, the apiVersion is 39.0. I have checked all closed tags. Should I try other version?